# How do I remove this tap valve?

Tags: faucet, taps

[image]
how to remove tap valve? Any suggestions?

Comment: including the make and model of the faucet might be helpful. Do you have the installation instructions?

Answer (score 1):

The round piece that is around the valve stem appears to be threaded into the outer body of the valve assembly. The internal hex shaped hole is used to accept a tool that fits over the valve stem and engages the inside shape to allow that round piece to be screwed out.

[image]

It is unlikely that a standard tool exists to extract the valve assembly and it may be necessary to contact the manufacturer to check on the availability of a specialized tool.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer so I can post a picture, but this is in addition to [Michael Karas's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/76663/43874).

There is a very common tool known as a "shower valve socket" that are sold individually and in sets at most stores that sell plumbing supplies.  I would *hope* the makers of the faucet used a somewhat standard size, but the sockets come in several sizes, so finding a close fit should be possible.

[image]